# Laravel 4 - Extract routes, iterate and test

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to extract the routes of a laravel 4 app and iterate them?

I was considering to use this to test each route in each iteration.

Here is an assumption:

```
$routes = Request::routes();

foreach($routes as $route)
{
    $crawler = $this->client->request($route->http_verb, $route->name);

    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need test routes using an array from Laravel.

The 'routing' code is already unit tested by the Laravel core. We know it works. If a route is correctly configured and defined, and is in the array of routes, then it will work.

By getting an array of routes from Laravel, then testing those routes against Laravel, you are just duplicating the unit tests that already exist.

You should explicitity tests routes you know and need. i.e. `/login` or `/dashboard`. Then if you change your code, and you remove the `/dashboard` route - you will get an error because that route no longer exists.

But if you are pulling the routes from Laravel itself - you will never get an error - since the `/dashboard` route is no longer in the array you are testing!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the class that manages the `routes` artisan command in console.

It's located in `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RoutesCommand`

You can easily find this class in the Laravel API page.

Also it works with this class `use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;`

**EDIT** I think `App::make('router')->getRoutes()` It returns a huge array, try to parse it a bit ;)

Comment: I was going to use a really ugly hack to get a list of my routes but your solution just made it that much simpler. Thanks you !